# Input mapping in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping

So in a lot of programming languages you have input mappings that looks something like this.

```
function mapping(input) {

var map = {
"case1" : "output1"
"case2" : "output2"
"case3" : "output3"
}

return map[input] || "output4"

}
```

And this basically works to replace a bunch of if/thens, as in:

```
var output;
If (input ==  "case1") {
output = "output1"
} else f (input ==  "case2") {
output = "output2"
} else f (input ==  "case3") {
output = "output3"
} else {
output = "output4"
} 
    
return output
```

My question is this... Is there a way to do this in SQL server to replace a bunch of when/thens in a case statement? So if this is my code (in reality I have a lot more cases)

```
SET someTable.SomeValue = (CASE
    WHEN Name = 'case1' THEN
    'output1'
    WHEN Name = 'case2' THEN
    'output2'
    WHEN Name = 'case3' THEN
    'output3'
    WHEN Name = 'case4' THEN
    "output4"
END) FROM TableName
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this? I.e. an input map or similar alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be to create a temporary table with the desired key as one column and the matching value as a second row. Then you can simply join to that table. No case statement required.

```
select id, val_col
from main
 inner join lookup
  on main.key_col = lookup.key_col
```

Given the following DDL:

```
create table main (id integer, key_col varchar(50));
create table lookup (key_col varchar(50), val_col varchar(50));

insert into main values (1, 'no good');
insert into lookup values ('no good', 'good');
```

If you want to do it on the fly, for instance with a Common table expression, proceed as follows:

```
with lookup as (
  select 'no good' key_col, 'good' val_col
  union
  select 'This I do not like' key_col, 'this I like' val_col
  union
  select 'Another unlikable one' key_col , 'also good' val_col ) 
select id, val_col
from main
 inner join lookup
  on main.key_col = lookup.key_col;
```

[See a demonstration in this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ac3c/1)

The closest thing to a key-value object in T-SQL is JSON, so you could create a temporary table with Jason values and parse that, although it's unclear how it improves on a basic temporary table.

[At the bottom of this page are some details on how it might work](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4850/key-value-pair-basics-for-sql-server-data/).